# bash script to edit file using sed doesn't persist reboot

Tags: bash, sed, raspberry-pi

I've written a script to migrate the `boot` directory from a microSD card to a USB drive.  This is for a raspberry pi 4 project.  As part of that script there are two files that get updated to remove the microSD reference and use UUID references of the USB thumb drive.  The script is run as `sudo`.  The script for updating the `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/etc/fstab` files are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

fCMDLINE=/boot/cmdline.txt
fFSTAB=/etc/fstab

cat $fCMDLINE
sed -i -r -e 's/PARTUUID=([a-z]\S*)/PARTUUID='"$vPARTUUID"'/g' $fCMDLINE
cat $fCMDLINE

cat $fFSTAB
sed -i -r -e 's/PARTUUID=([a-z]\S*)/\/dev\/disk\/by-uuid\/'"$vUUID"'/g' $fFSTAB
cat $fFSTAB
```

After running the entire script the pre & post files are as follows:

```
CMDLINE FILE

#ORIGINAL
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=d9b3f436-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

#UPDATED
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=0b1e4c33-0a73-4c26-aad2-03c1b5fd9266 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

FSTAB FILE

#ORIGINAL
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=d9b3f436-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=d9b3f436-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that

#UPDATED
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5bee13fa-5c62-45b0-91ed-12c544d4b528  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5bee13fa-5c62-45b0-91ed-12c544d4b528  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

The output for both files is correct and the sed command appears to have executed as expected on the replacement of the UUIDs.  But, when I reboot the raspberry pi the original `fstab` file is the one that persists and it isn't updated.  This only happens after the reboot.  Prior to that the files are correct and everything is mounted as expected.

```
#After Reboot

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=d9b3f436-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=d9b3f436-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Not that it should matter, but here are the two files with permissions.

```
/boot/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      191 Dec  8 01:01 cmdline.txt

/etc/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     314 Sep 26 01:31 fstab
```

The expected behavior would be for the `fstab` file to persist a reboot the same way the `cmdline.txt` file persists.  There must be something obviously that I'm just missing.  Any thoughts?

**update...**

I hadn't noticed before, but the two files above don't have the same date - - The 9/26 file is the original from the Buster (9/26) image and didn't update.  Before reboot the file is:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     382 Dec  8 18:16 fstab
```

Baffling - it makes me think it's a hardware issue or a much deeper OS bug.

Comment: Strange. You may have better luck on [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). You haven't moved any parts of your filesystem to tmpfs have you? You can check with `findmnt` at the command line.